# Using Linked Images in MS Access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I created a form in Microsoft Access 2013 with a listbox called `lstPhotoID` that is populated with photo names from a query.

I want to display, on the same form, a preview of the images as I click on (select) an image in the list.

I added an image box `imgPreview` and set the `Picture` property to `Linked` but beyond this I'm stuck.

Comment: Where are the images stored? Are they files?

Comment: you need to learn how to loop through listboxes and then how to set the image property of the control. Super simple and you can easily google your way into it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the lstPhotoID listbox control's record source a 2 column, e.g select from table name,column1,column2

Column 1 is the photoid field in the base table,while column2 to is the image field from the base table.

Then in the form,under after update event of the photoid control, place the following code
imgPreview=lstPhotoID.column(1)